# Sorting Nested Collection with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have the following nested classes. I am trying to sort at each level where appropriate on the DisplayOrder field

```
public class Menu
    {
        public virtual string MenuDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
        public virtual short SiteId { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<MenuHeader> MenuHeaders { get; set; }
    }

    public class MenuHeader 
    {
        public virtual string HeaderName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
        public virtual string DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<MenuCategory> MenuCategories { get; set; }
    }

   public class MenuCategory
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Icon { get; set; }
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
        public virtual string DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<MenuOptionHeader> MenuOptionHeaders { get; set; }
    }

 public class MenuOptionHeader
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
        public virtual string DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<MenuOption> MenuOptions { get; set; }
    }

 public class MenuOption 
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
        public virtual string DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

I am struggling to return all the data sorted at each level by DisplayOrder

I was attempting something like

```
menuRepository.GetAll(x => x.SiteId == _siteConfiguration.Id && x.Active == true)
              .SelectMany(x => x.MenuHeaders.OrderBy(d => d.DisplayOrder))
              .SelectMany(x1 => x1.MenuCategories.OrderBy(o => o.DisplayOrder))
              .SelectMany(x2 => x2.MenuOptionHeaders.OrderBy(o => o.DisplayOrder));
```

This only retuns a part dataset. How can I amend the linq to Return all the data sorted at each level by DisplayOrder

Comment: Why do you need the classes MenuOptionHeader and MenuOption? I mean, considering they have the same properties as MenuCategory.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are calling `OrderBy` on collection items doesn't make them ordered without reassigning result back. In your example you need extra variable that can store ordered items. Are your items disconnected from the store? If so, you can do something like this:

```
List<Menu> orderedItems = menuRepository
    .GetAll(x => x.SiteId == _siteConfiguration.Id && x.Active == true)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(m => 
    {
        m.MenuHeaders = m.MenuHeaders.OrderBy(d => d.DisplayOrder);
        m.MenuCategories = m.MenuCategories.OrderBy(d => d.DisplayOrder);
        m.MenuOptionHeaders = m.MenuOptionHeaders.OrderBy(d => d.DisplayOrder);
    });
```

Which will indeed assigns `IOrderedEnumerable` to nested properties.